# Compiling systemverilog packages with the same name

Tags: system-verilog

If I am not mistaken, once a package has been analyzed, its visibility is global (like that of a module, for example).

If the design and verification teams each have their own "common_pkg" package, is it possible to somehow compile them both and use design's common_pkg for design and verification's common_pkg for verification?

My idea was to limit their scope by encapsulating them in design/verification packages, like so:

```
package design_pkg;
  package common_pkg;
    typedef enum {<something>} my_type;
  endpackage : common_pkg
endpackage : design_pkg

package verification_pkg;
  package common_pkg;
    typedef enum {<something_else>} my_type;
  endpackage : common_pkg
endpackage : design_pkg

// In design:
design_pkg::common_pkg::my_type my_design_var;
// In verification:
verification_pkg::common_pkg::my_type my_verification_var;
```

But, it seems that package nesting is illegal in systemverilog, which is strange since module definitions can be nested.

Is there a solution for this problem, other than renaming the packages and avoiding too "broad" names such as "common_pkg" which might conflict with other areas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to system verilog :-(. Unfortunately SV does not provide any solution for package name collisions, nor any good way for any other type of naming collisions in global scope.

This is why you might hear the term 'uniquification' from some companies. It really means modifying source code in an automated way to uniquely name global scope items, like packages, modules, macros, ... for verilog building blocks coming from multiple teams (IPs).

So, the best solution is for your teams to talk to each other and agreed on using of names.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be great if engineering teams could work together and common_pkg really meant a common package *common* to all?

SystemVerilog has no built-in way of having multiple packages with the same name. Even if you could nest packages, the visibility of the package would be limited to the package it was enclosed in.

Some tools might allow you to compile and optimize the design with its package, and then bind the design unit as a whole.